# Concatenate a .xls file list into .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob, xls

I'm trying to concatenate a .xls file list into .csv:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

file_xls = glob.glob(location + "\*.xls")
print(file_xls)
read_file = pd.read_excel(location + file_xls)
```

but I have an error about the concatenation of the list:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Is there a specific way to concatenate this list? Thanks in advance!

Goal: Fuse the the .xls files into .csv with the help of a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of concatenating strings, you should use `os.path.join()`:

```
file_xls = glob.glob(location + "\*.xls")
```

Will return a list of all the file names in the specified root (defined by the user as `location`)

```
files = [pd.read_excel(os.path.join(location,x)) for x in file_xls]
```

Returns a list of all files as pandas DataFrames.

You can concat them by using [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and output them as csv with [df.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
output = pd.concat(files)
output.to_csv(desired_output_path)
```

You can also single line absolutely everything with:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(os.path.join(location,x)) for x in glob.glob(location + "\*.xls")]).to_csv(desired_output_path)
```